# Почему моё UEFI-приложение, написанное на языке Rust, не работает?

Tags: rust, ос, uefi

Заинтересовался темой разработки ОС. Решил начать с написания UEFI-программы, которая просто выведет на экран "Hello, World!".
Читал два туториала: [клац](https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/575630/) и [клац](https://rust-osdev.github.io/uefi-rs/HEAD/tutorial/app.html).
У меня есть следующий код:

```rust
#![no_std] 
#![no_main] 
#![feature(asm)] 
#![feature(abi_efiapi)] 
 
extern crate uefi; 
extern crate uefi_services; 
 
use log::info; 
use uefi::prelude::*; 
 
#[entry] 
fn main(_image_handler: uefi::Handle, mut system_table: SystemTable<Boot>) -> Status { 
    uefi_services::init(&mut system_table).expect("Failed to initialize the environment"); 
    info!("Hello, World!"); 
    system_table.boot_services().stall(10_000_000); 
    Status::SUCCESS 
}
```

Я собрал приложение efi с помощью
`cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-uefi`
Потом я пытался создать загружаемый файл ISO, у меня ничего не получалось: виртуальная машина VMWare выдавала ошибку "ОС не найдена".

Тогда я просто взял образ Windows 11, убрал из него все файлы, кроме /boot/efi/bootx64.efi и заменил этот файл на своё приложение. Теперь-то ошибка не найденной ОС исчезла и при запуске появляется Press any key to boot from CD or DVD... Я жму кнопку, но "Hello, World!" не выводится на экран. VMWare просто запускает какой-то EFI Network.

Что я делаю не так?

P.S. Если файл bootx64.efi поставить тот, что был в дистрибутиве Windows, он будет загружаться! А мой - нет...